# Tomcat Server can not find this Spring ContextLoaderListener class during the server start up

Tags: jsf, tomcat, spring-security

the Error is:

```
INFO: The listener "org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
mai 14, 2013 11:19:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Erreur lors de la configuration de la classe d'écoute de l'application (application listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

I try this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-error-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderlistener/  but no result.
I use

- tomcat 7.0.
- jsf 2.0
- spring security 3.0.6

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>plateformHotlin</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>redmond</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping> 
   <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
<!-- ////////////////////////// END: FACES RELATED ///////////////////////// -->

<!-- ========================== SPRING RELATED ============================= -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
         /WEB-INF/security-app-context.xml
         /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
    </filter>  
    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>  
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>  
    </filter-mapping> 

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/j_spring_security_logout</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
<!-- ////////////////////////// END: SPRING RELATED //////////////////////// -->
</web-app>
```

Comment: pls add web.xml to the question

Comment: in your  <param-value> definition, you need to separate the xml files with a comma, like this:  /WEB-INF/security-app-context.xml, /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml